# Css no carga tipografía

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo una página web con una hoja de estilos en la que importa las tipografías (descargadas, enlazando los .ttf). El caso es que abriendo el archivo html desde el PC se ve todo correctamente, pero al cargar la página desde el servidor web no se aplican las tipografías.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no todos los navegadores pueden leer los diferentes formatos de archivos de fuente, en el siguiente fragmento de código te digo como solucionarlo:

```
@font-face{
font-family: "(fuente que quieras utilizar)"; //nombre de la tipografía (ejemplo:"Arial")
src: url("carpeta-fuente/fuente.ttf"); //para buscar el archivo con tu fuente
src: local(?), //en caso de que el navegador no la encuente(o no pueda leer el archivo) elegirá los siguientes formatos
    url("carpeta-fuente/fuente.woff") format("woff"), //especificas el nombre del archivo con el formato.
    url("carpeta-fuente/fuente.ttf") format("truetype");//especificas el nombre del archivo con el formato
}
```

El ejemplo que te acabo de mostrar es pensando en una tipografía, pero con varios formatos de archivos.

He puesto 2 formatos pero puedes añadir tantos como existan y con diferentes fuentes.

Está es la primera paginá que encontre sobre formatos de archivos de fuentes, pero está bien: https://www.paredro.com/la-guia-de-tipos-de-formatos-de-fuentes-digitales/

Comment: No las reconoce ningún navegador entonces... Pero en local por qué si que las reconoce?

Comment: Has puesto bien la dirección del directorio? A lo mejor el problema esta en que las fuentes no las guardas en la misma ruta

Comment: Si. Están puestas las rutas exactamente igual que en local. De hecho, al subirlas por FTP copio las 3 carpetas directamente, por lo que las subcarpetas (css y fontanería) están en la misma ubicación.

Comment: Y están en una ruta en la que el navegador puede acceder a ellas. Me refiero a que si tú inspeccionas la página desde el navegador y accedes a "Source", puedes ver los archivos de tipografía?

Comment: Pues debería ser así. He seguido el mismo procedimiento que con el resto de web que he hecho, salvo que esta vez no las carga.

Answer (score 0):

Después de tanto tiempo ya lo habrás solucionado
es la primera vez que busco tipografía y así resulto encontrar una tipografía en mi pc, src: local no pude utilizarlo.

```
*
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

@font-face{
 font-family: Sesat-Normal;
 src: url("SESAT-DEMO.ttf");
}

h1
{
 font-family: Sesat-Normal;   
}
```

Comment: Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente cómo esta respuesta responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.